# MVC Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to get my Ajax.BeginForm to run a function OnSuccess but I keep getting in firebug the error message:

```
UpdateProjectDiv is not defined
 return Function.constructor.apply(null, argNames);
```

Here's what the form looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function UpdateProjectDiv() {
            var projid = $("#ddlProjectsManage").val();

            $.post("/Manage/ProjectEmployeeList/", { projectid: projid }, function (data) {
                populateDiv($("#divProjectsToFill"), data);
            });
        }

        function populateDiv(div, data) {
            div.html('');
            div.append(data);
        }

    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MoveToProject", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divAllEmployeesToFill", OnSuccess = "UpdateProjectDiv" }))
{
    [insert non-relevant code here] 

    <input id="btnMoveEmpsToProject" type="submit" value=">>"  />
    @Html.Hidden("SelectedProjectID","9999999999999")
}
```

And My controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MoveToProject(UnassignedEmployeeBindingModel model, int selectedprojectId)
{
    var tempteam = _db.SpecTeams.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "N/A" && s.ProjectId == selectedprojectId);

    try
    {
        foreach (var employee in model.UnassignedEmployees)
        {
            var employeeObj = _db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == employee.Employee.Id);

            if (employee.IsSelected)
            {
                employeeObj.SpecTeamId = tempteam.Id;
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("UnassignedEmployeeList");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Without the OnSucess the code it works fine, except it doesn't refresh the div in another partial (#divProjectsToFill) automatically.

Additionally it seems to be looking for the function UpdateProjectDiv in the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file rather than on the page itself. I suppose I might be able to add my function in that file (although I haven't tried yet) but that does not sound like a proper solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try defining your (JavaScript) functions outside of `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple... Thank you! Put it as answer so I can mark it as solved. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Break your function definitions outside of the `$(document).ready(...)` event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateProjectDiv() {
        var projid = $("#ddlProjectsManage").val();

        $.post("/Manage/ProjectEmployeeList/", { projectid: projid }, function (data) {
            populateDiv($("#divProjectsToFill"), data);
        });
    }

    function populateDiv(div, data) {
        div.html('');
        div.append(data);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () { /*... */});
</script>
```

Comment: can you please give the reason, why do we need  to break the function definitions outside the $(document).ready(...) event handler???

Comment: @psylogic: If you define `UpdateProjectDiv` inside of `$(document).ready(...)`, `UpdateProjectDiv` will be scoped to the function you pass to the `ready` function, and therefore invisible to ASP.NET MVC's JavaScript. When you define it outside of the `$(document).ready(...)` function, it is global and available to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @psylogic: Glad to help. I should add that it's usually not a good practice to create global functions like this. A better practice would be to put the function in a namespace using a pattern like the "revealing module" pattern.